# Spring Boot Security MVC + AngularJS logout not working

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a problem with logging out from Spring Boot https using AngularJS. After successful logout when i refresh the page(using F5) i still get first logged user in this window session.

I'm using basic authetication and my tomcat has two ports: 

8090 - http

8443 - https

8090 is used to redirect for a secured session.

I have tried many solutions but none have worked so far.

This is my configuration:
**application.properties**

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=****.p12
server.ssl.key-storepassword=*****
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias=*****
```

**SpringBoot main class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class DanceSchoolManagementApplication {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };

        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(initiateHttpConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector initiateHttpConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(8090);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(8443);

        return connector;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DanceSchoolManagementApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ManagementSecurityProperties managementSecurityProperties;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private LogoutSuccess logoutSuccess;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
//                .authenticated()
            .fullyAuthenticated()

//                .and()
//                .logout()
//                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
//                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
//                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccess)
//                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
//                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
//                .permitAll()

            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())

            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(createDaoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    private DaoAuthenticationProvider createDaoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(createBCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder createBCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(managementSecurityProperties.getBcryptStrength());
    }


}
```

As you see i have tried many different configuration options including creating own LogoutSuccessHandlers, trying to delete cookies and invalidating session but any of it worked for me.

Below is the custom logout rest method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/auth/logout")
public boolean logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(auth != null) {
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request,response,auth);
            auth = null;
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            SecurityContextHolder.setContext(SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext());
        }

        return true;
}
```

But still i was able to get authenticated user data after refreshing the page:

Here is the angular login and logout:

**Auth Service**

```
angular.module("danceSchoolManagement.authService",[])
.factory("authService", function ($http) {
    var service = {};

    service.authenticate = function(credentials, successFunction, failureFunction) {
        var headers = credentials ? {
            authorization: "Basic "
            + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
        } : {};

        $http.get('/login/user', {headers: headers})
            .success(successFunction)
            .error(failureFunction);
    };

    service.logout = function(successFunction, failureFunction) {
        $http.post('/auth/logout', {})
            .success(successFunction)
            .error(failureFunction);
    };

    return service;
});
```

**Login Controller**

```
angular.module("danceSchoolManagement.authController", [])
.controller("authController", function ($rootScope, $scope, authService) {

    $scope.credentials = {};

    $scope.authenticate = function (credentials) {
        authService.authenticate(credentials,
            function (returnedData) {
                $rootScope.user = returnedData;
            }, function (returnedData) {
                $rootScope.user = null;
            });
    };

    $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.authenticate($scope.credentials);
    };

    $scope.authenticate();

    $scope.logout = function () {
        authService.logout(
            function (returnedData) {
                $rootScope.user = null;
            }, function (returnedData) {
                $rootScope.user = null;
            });
    };
});
```